# Swift Firebase Twitter Login: Unable to get credential

Tags: swift, firebase, twitter, firebase-authentication

I am implementing Firebase Authentication with Twitter login and I followed the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/twitter-login) but wasn't able to get any response from `getCredentialWith`. Other SO post on this topic is outdated as most still uses TwitterKit, which has already stopped being supported.

My implementation so far:

```
//At viewDidLoad()
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Login", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(loginWithTwitter))

@objc func loginWithTwitter() {
    print("Login button tapped") 
    let provider = OAuthProvider(providerID: "twitter.com")

    provider.getCredentialWith(nil) { credential, error in
        print(2) // <== Not printed
        if error != nil {
            // Handle error.
            print("Err", error)
        }
        
        if let credential = credential {
            Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { authResult, error in
                print(3) // <== Not printed
                if error != nil {
                    // Handle error.
                    print("Err auth", error)

                }
                
                if let authResult = authResult {
                    print(authResult.credential)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Oddly, the above code, as copy and pasted from the docs, doesn't seem to return to print `2`.

I have ensured that I have done the following:

- Added URL schemes to the Info tab
- Enabled Twitter sign in on Firebase Authentication
- Added the necessary API key and secret key on Firebase Auth
- Added callback URL to Twitter developer dashboard

What am I missing?

Comment: Explain this line `provider.getCredentialWith(nil) { credential, error in`

Comment: @TinNguyen its in the docs. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/twitter-login#handle_the_sign-in_flow_with_the_firebase_sdk

Comment: I can't make sense of that syntax. Tried looking up the syntax but it makes no sense to me. It's not a method definition. You are calling an existing method there. So the curly brackets make no sense to me. And the `error in` followed by an `if` in the next line also makes no sense to me. --- Wait nevermind. That's Swift, not JavaScript. It's some Swift specific syntax and that's why your `print(2)` is not evaluated.

Answer (score 4):

I managed to solve it by:

1. Adding a website URL to the authentication settings in Twitter Developer portal
2. Moving `let provider = OAuthProvider(providerID: "twitter.com")` to a global variable

Comment: Moving that line to a global scope did the trick. How bizarre.